# Perl Update in OS X 10.10.5, Cannot Locate Perl Modules

Tags: perl, osx-yosemite, perl-module, cpan

**UPDATE:** I tried again and realized that perl said that when it tried to load the module, it got a "permission denied" error. So, I just re-ran the script using sudo...and it worked. I guess it must be some sort of permissions changes.

Original:

I just updated OS X to 10.10.5 and suddenly, Perl can no longer locate any of my CPAN-installed modules. Even newly installed modules are not found. I know that the update installed Perl 5.18.2, but even when I explicitly use 5.16, the modules still cannot be located.

The output of perl -V is here:

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 18 subversion 2) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=darwin, osvers=14.0, archname=darwin-thread-multi-2level
    uname='darwin osx228.apple.com 14.0 darwin kernel version 14.0.0: tue jun 2 11:49:04 pdt 2015; root:xnu-2782.1.97.1.3~1development_x86_64 x86_64 '
    config_args='-ds -e -Dprefix=/usr -Dccflags=-g  -pipe  -Dldflags= -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseithreads -Duseshrplib -Dinc_version_list=none -Dcc=cc'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector',
    optimize='-Os',
    cppflags='-g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc -mmacosx-version-min=10.10.5', ldflags ='-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fstack-protector'
    libpth=/usr/lib /usr/local/lib
    libs= 
    perllibs=
    libc=, so=dylib, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.dylib
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=bundle, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags='-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                        PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_HASH_FUNC_ONE_AT_A_TIME_HARD
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP
                        PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV PERL_SAWAMPERSAND USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
                        USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API
  Locally applied patches:
    /Library/Perl/Updates/ comes before system perl directories
    installprivlib and installarchlib points to the Updates directory
  Built under darwin
  Compiled at Jul  9 2015 01:30:43
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/Users/jrg/perl5/lib/perl5:"
    PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=":/Users/jrg/perl5"
    PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base /Users/jrg/perl5"
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/jrg/perl5"
  @INC:
    /Users/jrg/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/jrg/perl5/lib/perl5
    /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.18
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18
    .
```

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've found the newly installed modules in /Library/Perl/5.18/.

Comment: How can you "explicitly use 5.16"? Wasn't it replaced by 5.18?

Comment: They don't remove the old versions, so you can point to whichever version you want.

Comment: I can help you with the old version problem, if you want. Start a new question. Provide `perl -V` from that version. Specify where the modules `perl` can't find are located. (Search your entire drive for a module you installed if you need to.)

Answer (score 0):

Locating them is not going to help. You need to reinstall them anyway. Perl doesn't maintain binary API compatibility between version (though you can safely upgrade to a newer release of the same version).

Comment: On another Mac of mine, I freshly installed CPAN and had the same issue. Perl can't find any modules, old or new.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and answer this as I figured out a way for it to work, though it poses yet another question: Why were permissions changed for where Perl modules are installed? Thankfully, this is only on my dev computers and nothing is accessed via the web, for which I use linux servers.

I tried again and realized that perl said that when it tried to load the module, it got a "permission denied" error. So, I just re-ran the script using sudo...and it worked. I guess it must be some sort of permissions changes.